# What is the reserved argument in azure app service plan terraform config

Tags: azure-app-service-plans, terraform-provider-azure

While writing config for App Service Plan, I came across the argument *reserved* in the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service_plan.html)

> reserved - (Optional) Is this App Service Plan Reserved. Defaults to false.

I am not sure what this *reserved* argument would do if set to true, except that there is a note stating it must be set to true for Linux plan.

Couldn't find that property in [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest) either. Also I don't see that property while creating the plan through portal.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes please accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your issue, just as the node shows you that it must be set to true for Linux plan. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#management) is a question in the Azure document for Linux service plan, it says if you want to create a Linux service plan, just set the reserved field to true. And there is also an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36849#issuecomment-534145820) in the Github, it shows this:

> If you set "kind": "linux" but without setting "reserved": true, it
>   deploys a Windows service plan with a Linux icon!

So just as the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/createorupdate#request-body) shows in the REST API, the reserved field decides the service plan is Linux or other types.